# return array with json and codeigniter

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json, codeigniter

I want to create a facility to print the data with a combination of ajax, json, and CodeIgniter. but when the data is returned, the error occurs in ajax. I've made ​​the ajax and the controller.

ajax

```
    formPembayaran.on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var serialized = $(this).serialize(), print = [];
            $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo base_url('pembayaran/simpanitempembayaran'); ?>',
            data: serialized,
            success: function(value){
                print['head'] = value.print.head;
                print['body'] = value.print.body;
                print['foot'] = value.print.foot;
            }
        });
        if (print.status === true) {
            var popup = '<!DOC'+'TYPE HT'+'ML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HT'+'ML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">' +
            '<ht'+'ml><he'+'ad><title>Cetak Materi Iklan Baris</title>' +
            '<st'+'yle type="text/css">' +
                    '@media print {' +
                            'body {' +
                                    'font-size: 11px;' +
                            '}' +
                            'button#printing {' +
                                    'display: none;' +
                            '}' +
                    '}' +
                    '.center, h3 {' +
                            'text-align: center;' +
                    '}' +
                    'div#page_head {' +
                            '-webkit-column-count: 2; -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em; -moz-column-count: 2; -moz-column-gap: 1.5em; -o-column-count: 2; -o-column-gap: 1.5em; column-count: 2; column-gap: 1.5em;' +
                    '}' +
                    'div#page_body {' +
                            '-webkit-column-count: 2; -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em; -moz-column-count: 2; -moz-column-gap: 1.5em; -o-column-count: 2; -o-column-gap: 1.5em; column-count: 2; column-gap: 1.5em;' +
                    '}' +
                    '#page_body, #page_foot {' +
                            'margin-top: 10px;' +
                    '}' +
            '</st'+'yle>' +
            '</he'+'ad><bo'+'dy>' +
            '<button id="printing" type="button" onClick="javascript:window.print();">Cetak Materi</button>' +
            '<pre>' +
            '<div id="content">' +
            '<div id="page_head">' + print.head + '</div>' +
            '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------' +
            '<div id="page_body">' + print.body + '</div>' +
            '<div id="page_foot">' + print.foot + '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</pre>' +
            '</bo'+'dy></ht'+'ml>';
            var width = 860;
            var height = 800;
            var left = (screen.width/2)-(width/2);
            var top = (screen.height/2)-(height/2);
            var testpopup = window.open('','Printer','toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+width+', height='+height+', top='+top+', left='+left);
            testpopup.document.write(popup);
            testpopup.document.close();
        }
        return false;

    });
```

controller with json

```
function simpanItemPembayaran() {

    $idMakanan = $this->input->post('id-makanan');
    $namaMakanan = $this->input->post('nama-makanan');
    $hargaMakanan = $this->input->post('harga-makanan');

    $idMinuman = $this->input->post('id-minuman');
    $hargaMinuman = $this->input->post('harga-minuman');

    $tanggalItemPembayaran = $this->input->post('tanggal-pembayaran');
    $tanggalPembayaran = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($tanggalItemPembayaran));
    $idKasir = $this->input->post('id-kasir');

    if (($idMakanan[0] == NULL) && ($idMinuman[0] == NULL)) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flashError', '<b>WARNING!</b> Form pembayaran makanan dan minuman kosong');
    } else {
        foreach ($idMakanan as $keyMakanan => $makananId) {
            if ($makananId != NULL) {
                $simpanItemMakanan = $this->pembayaran_model->insertItemMakanan($makananId, $hargaMakanan[$keyMakanan], $tanggalPembayaran, $idKasir);
            }
        }

        foreach ($idMinuman as $keyMinuman => $minumanId) {
            if ($minumanId != NULL) {
                $simpanItemMinuman = $this->pembayaran_model->insertItemMinuman($minumanId, $hargaMinuman[$keyMinuman], $tanggalPembayaran, $idKasir);
            }
        }
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flashSuccess', 'Berhasil menyimpan item makanan atau minuman ke database');
        $print['status'] = true;
        $print['head'] = '<b>PT. BP. Kedaulatan Rakyat</b><br/>';
        $print['head'] = '<b>PT. BP. Kedaulatan Rakyat</b><br/>';
        $print['head'] = '<b>PT. BP. Kedaulatan Rakyat</b><br/>';
        $print['body'] = '<b>PT. BP. Kedaulatan Rakyat</b><br/>';
        $print['body'] = '<b>PT. BP. Kedaulatan Rakyat</b><br/>';
        $print['body'] = '<b>PT. BP. Kedaulatan Rakyat</b><br/>';
        $print['foot'] = '<b>Website : www.kr.co.id; E-mail : alamatemail@mail.com; Bank yyy Cabang www No. TTT</b>';
    }
    echo json_encode(array('print'=>$print));
}
```

error occurs when restoring data to ajax. please help. thank you

Comment: what is the exact error you found during this url request?? and i don't think you url reach on the right URL.

Comment: What do you get in the success function? `value.print.head;` is this get the head in the print arr?

Comment: Can you post your sample json structure?

Comment: can you please tell me what is the result of console.log(print.status); if you put it right above the if statement?

Comment: @bondythegreat: undefined from console.log(print.status);

Answer (score 0):

as i see in your code

```
type: 'POST',
url: '<?php echo base_url('pembayaran/simpanitempembayaran'); ?>',
```

should be :

```
type: 'POST',
url: '<?php echo base_url("pembayaran/simpanitempembayaran"); ?>',
```

**UPDATE:** here is an example to display the json data. http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/CRAcC/1/

Comment: I think not problem with my url, but can't call data from return json to ajax.

Comment: @user1878292 please check the updated answer, and go through the jsfiddle, hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

try including `dataType: 'json'`  to your ajax call
dataType is The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.

```
  $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '<?php echo base_url('pembayaran/simpanitempembayaran'); ?>',
            data: serialized,
            success: function(value){
                print['head'] = value.print.head;
                print['body'] = value.print.body;
                print['foot'] = value.print.foot;
            }
        });
```

or you can use `$.getJSON` instead of ajax